# Mobaxterm installed from scoop does not work. When open a session like bash/powershell etc it closes immediatley

Tags: mobaxterm, scoop-installer

I have recently installed Mobaxterm on my Window's 10 machine after I removed the "Ubuntu" sub system. 
And then I re-installed Mobaxterm using scoop but it does not work properly.If I open any session/terminal it just closed immediately and never opens up. Any suggestion are welcome.

Comment: Post log from Help -> View MobaXterm log file

Comment: What is scoop? Why not install an official version from their website?

Comment: As I wanted use scoop to manage installations instead of doing it manually